# how to delete a particular attribute from LDAP using spring template

Tags: spring, unbind, spring-ldap

I am using the following code for the delete process:

```
public void delete(Person p) {
  Name dn = buildDn(p);
  ldapTemplate.unbind(dn);
}
```

but using the `unbind()` method, it will delete all the attributes, but I want to delete only a particular attribute from LDAP, such as the role of the person.

Answer (score 0):

For attribute modifications you should use the `DirContextAdapter`, as described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/#adding-and-updating-data-using-dircontextadapter). The section that applies to your requirement would be section 3.2.2 (Updating); to remove an attribute value you should use [`removeAttributeValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/DirContextAdapter.html#removeAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

There are three modes:

- **MOD_ADD:** This is used to add an attribute value. If the attribute already exists (and the schema permits multiple values), the new
  value will be added, and the old value will remain.
- **MOD_DELETE:** The attribute value will be removed, if it exists.
- **MOD_REPLACE:** The given attribute values will replace all other values for that attribute name. In other words, all old values for
  the attribute will be deleted, and then this value will be added.

you should to use MOD_REPLACE

```
>>> mod_attrs = [ (ldap.MOD_DELETE, 'cn','Francis Bacon') ]
>>> l.modify_s('uid=francis,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com', mod_attrs)
(103, [])
>>>
```

This will remove only the attribute value Francis Bacon from the cn attribute. If no such value exists, a NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE exception will be raised. Otherwise, the value will be discarded.

source :https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/python-ldap-applications-part-3-more-ldap-operations-and-ldap-url-library

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know field value then use None as value like this (taking example of @Anouar Mokhtari):

```
mod_attrs = [ (ldap.MOD_DELETE, 'cn', None) ]
l.modify_s('uid=francis,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com', mod_attrs)
```